# Probability of $x^3+y^3$ being a multiple of $3$ vs $7$

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

If the numbers $x,\,y$ are randomly selected with replacement from $1$ to $n\ge3$. We have to show that $P(3|x^3+y^3)<P(7|x^3+y^3)$.

I could only check it up against some examples but could not get to the general proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the cases for $x^3+y^3$ modulo $3$:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x\pmod3& y\pmod3 & x^3+y^3\pmod3 \\\hline
0 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1\\ \hline
0 & 2 & 2\\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1\\ \hline
1 & 1 & 2\\ \hline
1 & 2 & 0\\ \hline
2 & 0 & 2\\ \hline
2 & 1 & 0\\ \hline
2 & 2 & 1\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

So, assuming that $n$ is a positive multiple of 3, you can see that the probability that $3$ divides $x^3+y^3$ is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Now, let's think about the same modulo $7$.  I don't feel like writing out $49$ cases, but let's start by looking at the cubes:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
x\pmod7 & x^3\pmod7\\\hline
0 & 0\\\hline
1 & 1\\\hline
2 & 1\\\hline
3 & 6\\\hline
4 & 1\\\hline
5 & 6\\\hline
6 & 6\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
So, how can we get the sum of cubes to be a multiple of seven?  There are three cases:

1. $x,y\equiv0\pmod7$
2. $x\pmod7\in\{1,2,4\}$ and $y\pmod7\in\{3, 5, 6\}$
3. $x\pmod7\in\{3, 5, 6\}$ and $y\pmod7\in\{1, 2, 4\}$

Assuming that $n$ is a positive multiple of $7$, these have combined probability of
$$
\frac{1}{49}+\frac{9}{49}+\frac{9}{49}=\frac{19}{49}>\frac{1}{3}.
$$

SO, under the assumption that $n$ is a multiple of $21$ (that is, of both $3$ and $7$), the result holds.  How would you do it for general $n$?  You can break into cases based on the values of $n\pmod3$ and $n\pmod7$.  All that will change is the step where you compute the probabilities from the table.  However, I haven't worked that out to verify that the result holds in general.